# What do istyle attributes do and what are the values available?

Tags: html, forms

I was looking up some codes and noticed that there were istyle attributes. Searching for their meaning, I found some few and outdated articles which only showed istyle attribute values from 1 - 4, but the codes I'd looked up used istyle values ranging from 5-15. Any idea what these values mean?

Comment: Some sample code would help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical reference appears to have been this (now offline):

https://web.archive.org/web/20060927020810/http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/p_s/i/tag/istyle.html

> - istyle was added as an attribute for INPUT type= "text" and TEXTAREA tags.
> - This attribute sets the default character input mode (alphabetic, numeric, etc.)
> - ...

It's part of the definition of cHTML, which is part of [i-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-mode), something like the mostly-Japan equivalent of [WAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol), an "internet for mobile devices before there was internet on mobile devices." It's all mostly obsolete and defunct now that smart phones have full featured browsers and fast connections to the real internet.

The `istyle` attribute in particular is for setting the default input mode, which can be two different forms of Japanese input, Latin alphabet, or numeric input. The additional numbers may have been for when i-mode had a [brief stint in countries other than Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-mode#Markets).

There may or may not be other technologies which use that attribute, but these will be even more obscure than i-mode is nowadays. Suffice it to say that [it's not part of the current HTML standard](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahtml.spec.whatwg.org%20%22istyle%22).